# Is there a way to display the javascript blob (.pdf) using google docs viewer without saving the file locally?

Tags: javascript, android, pdf, mobile, blob

I am able to pass the http PDF link to google docs viewer and display it without any issues:

window.open("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url={pdfLink}", "_blank");

**but** is there a way to display the PDF from javascript blob on google docs viewer without saving the file locally?

Meaningful suggestions will be appreciated.